# Running into AngularJS performance issues with web workers, fast timers, and $scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, twitter-bootstrap, web-worker

I have a timer that runs in a web worker with a 10 millisecond interval.  Each time the timer ticks, a function is called in the controller which increments a variable.  This variable is used by a bootstrap progress bar on my page.

The problem that I'm encountering is that the progress bar doesn't update unless I call $scope.$apply() in the function call where the value gets updated.

Meanwhile, I have an array with a bunch of complex objects in them (100+ objects) that are on the $scope.  Since I need to call $scope.$apply() in order to have the view take the changes every time my timer ticks, it's also updating this list of objects (every 10ms), which is slowing down my application.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could potentially resolve this issue?  Please let me know if I can provide additional details.

Comment: With the 100+ objects that you mentioned, are you doing anything with them on the front end? For example, ng-switch, ng-repeat, show/hide etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an ng-repeat to render some data to the view.  I've already experimented by removing this, however, and the performance was still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the elements for the 100+ objects aren't all actually visible on screen at any one time, you can only include the ones on screen in the DOM (and so only have watchers for them) by using something like https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat (a colleague of mine had to hack it slightly to get it to do exactly what was needed: I forget the details)

Comment: I mentioned this in reply above, but the bottleneck doesn't appear to be related to the view.  I've removed all references to the complex-object-array from the view, and the performance still stays the same, because the data model still has this list on the $scope, and $scope.$apply() is being called every 10ms.

Comment: @Novark Having `$scope.myVariable = something` doesn't cause a slowdown when the digest cycle runs, as Angular doesn't check everything on the scope. It has to have some watchers associated with it, created either by calling `$watch` or by referencing them somehow in the template. (However, if not having the items in the template doesn't help, then this point is just for your reference, I don't think it helps your immediate problem...)

Comment: I actually found the source of the slowdown.  I forgot that I had an ng-repeat on the complex object list in my view that I was using as a placeholder / debug area.  It's a bit odd to me that this is responsible for the slowdown though, as it's just a simple ng-repeat on a <td>{{entry}}</td> where entry is one of the objects in my large list.  So all it's really adding to the view is a text representation of the object.  Thanks again for helping me with my issue though - it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variables only need to be updates in a certain `$scope`, you can call `$scope.$digest()` on that `$scope`. As opposed to `$apply()`, `$digest()` will only run the watchers on that `$scope` (and its children) rather than throughout the application.

Comment: My application currently only has one controller - something I'll probably eventually get around to changing, but is there a way to selectively exclude certain items on the $scope to *not* update when $scope.$digest() is called?  Something along the lines of $scope.$digest(exclude = $scope.myComplexList)?

Answer (score 0):

An update every 10 milliseconds is extremely frequent. If everything keeps up, this would be 100 updates a second: around 4 times the frame rate of a lot of video formats. A very simple way of speeding things up is to reduce this considerably.

One way I can think of doing this that would probably fit in with most architectures is to use a throttle function, such as `_.throttle' from [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
var throttledApply = _.throttle($scope.apply, 500);
```

And then when you receive a message, you would have something like:

```
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  // ... Other processing code ...
  throttledApply();
};
```

If you're using the Bootstrap progress bar, it should still give a smooth transition between displayed values, even if the differences between them are large.

Comment: I agree, 10ms is very fast.  This wasn't so much a requirement of updating the progress bar (as you mentioned, bootstrap can animate the bar for me), as much as it was required for me to do some additional processing each timer tick.  I'm currently investigating whether I can increase the time delay, while still preserving the application behaviour that I'm after.

Comment: @Novark I've added a suggested way you can throttle the calls to `$scope.apply`